# How do I handle jQuery .ajax responses from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to figure out how to process a response from a server (server returning either true or false (json encoded)) with ajax / query:

```
function submitFormWithAjax(form) {
    form = $(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: (form.attr('method')),
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    var serverResponse = eval(result.responseText);
    console.log(serverResponse);
    return serverResponse;
}
```

now when I console log the result, there property responseText is showing as true/false correctly, however the function always seems to return true.  I am not a javascript / jquery programmer, so if what I am doing above looks 'stupid' forgive me, I am trying to piece things together.

-- Correction, the function always returns false (not true as I stated above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably closer to the right way of doing this....

```
$("#SomeButtonThatOpensDialog").click(function()
{
    $("#ElementWithForm").dialog({
        // dialog options here
        buttons: {
            Submit: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    // ajax options
                    success: function(data, status, xhttp)
                    {     
                        if ( data )
                        {
                          // if true
                          $("#ElementWithForm").dialog("destroy");
                        }
                        else 
                    { // if false, show some sort of message with errors
                            alert("OH NO!");
                        }                      
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I understand the processing logic there, that even simplifies things a little better.  Thanks!

Comment: Changed the correct answer to this one as it helps me process things a bit easier.

Answer (score 3):

```
function submitFormWithAjax(form) {
    var form = $(form);
    var ret = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: (form.attr('method')),
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function( data, status, xhttp) {
             // data will be true or false if you returned a json bool
             ret = data;
        },
        async: false // this is generally bad, it will lock up your browser while it returns, but the only way to fit it into your pattern.
    });
    return ret;
}
```

There is also a plugin that does a little of the work for you:
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Oh, also, pay attention to the case of your property and value names.  I think "dataType" needs to be "datatype"

I'm not nuts about this solution, but it gets you where you need to be.  I think you need to refactor a bit to make it work properly asynchronously.

Comment: ok, adjusted my code (added the success part), however, maybe I am misinterpreting what is happening, because alert and console log are both showing correctly true/false (boolean not string), however the function submitFormWithAjax(form), is what I need to 'return' the results from, and I think that is where it is failing (is always returning false)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I suppose you can make the ajax call synchronously, although not the greatest solution...  I'll update code...

Comment: ok, maybe I better revise my question if we have to turn off async for this solution.  Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a form (Zend_Form) on my server that loads into a modal dialog on the client, and with a click event (jquery), I submit the form.

Ultimately what I want is if the form submission is successful (based on the server response) i want the dialog to close, otherwise I want it to redisplay the form (with the errors) in the dialog

Comment: I am going to flag this as correct, as it is returning the correct value now none the less.  But any suggestions / links to tutorials, on how to better accomplish my goal in my previous question would be great (without using async: false)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are returning a string that looks like a bool.  What does result.responseText look like if you log it to the console like `console.log(result.responseText)`? Does it contain quotes?

If I am right you might want to do  something like this:  `var serverResponse = $.parseJSON($.parseJSON(result.responseText))`

If it is a string and you can change it to not be a string you should do so and go with Darthg8r's answer.

Comment: yes it is boolean (not a string), per comments (see @Darthg8r comments area) looks more an issue from the function, rather than the ajax call inside I think.